# Resources for GUI in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am making an image processing application in Java. I have written all the code for the processing part, I just need to make a user interface for the same. The user interface looks like this :

It has a browse button to select an image, Once an image is selected, it is to be displayed. The user can now  select multiple rectangular regions on this image using mouse (the user clicks at a point in the image and drags mouse to select the region of interest). All selected regions appear shaded. The selected regions also appear in a list, so the regions can be un-selected by deleting the corresponding entry from the list. Finally the user can click on a "process" button to perform the image processing.

I want to know what java gui technologies do i need to create such an interface, and any good resources from where i can read the same. I need resources, for example, about how to manage the layout, display images, mouse events on images etc.

Answer (score 6):

Read the Java trail about [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

You will find better answers there than here.

Also, you can use [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/); it has a great GUI editor. Or you can check out Google [WindowBuilder Pro](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/download-wbpro.html) and install it in your [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/).